# Jquery code not working in wordpress divi theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to integrate Jquery code in wordpress divi theme in the following section **as shown in the screenshot below** but it doesn't seems to work and I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

[image]

The JQuery code which I have included in the screenshot is mentioned in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwrddefk/embedded/result/).

The snippets of the JQuery code used in the fiddle are:

```
$("#franchisehub").click(function() {
  if ($('.franchisehubtv').css('display') == "flex") {
    $('.franchisehubtv').css('display', 'none');

  } else {
    $('.franchisehubtv').css('display', 'flex'); 
    $('.cloudbasedtextipad').css('display', 'none');
    $('.business-analytics').css('display', 'none');
    $('.tech-support').css('display', 'none');
    $('.order-management').css('display', 'none');
    $('.employee-management').css('display', 'none');
    $('.white-label').css('display', 'none');
    $('.brand-control').css('display', 'none');
    $('.lead-tracking').css('display', 'none');
    $('.custom-invoicing').css('display', 'none');
    $('.goal-setting').css('display', 'none');
    $('.customization-tools').css('display', 'none');
    $('.royalty-calculator').css('display', 'none');
    $('.email-marketing').css('display', 'none');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wordpress themes usually use [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) which removes `window.$` alias for jQuery

Just wrap your code in

```
// IIFE to enable `$` as jQuery
;(function($){
   // document ready
   $(function(){
      // your code
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Added link to explain why

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery` instead of `$`.
WordPress is running jQuery in compatibility mode.

Comment: Just a heads up. For answers of lasting value, and that accrue upvotes as result, it's always nice explain the *why* and cite official docs. See accepted answer ;)